# Await and .then not getting Axios Promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, axios

I am tracing my way through an application i am building. I have numbered steps to figure out what is getting called and what is not.

I call Axios and try to call .then() to get the data from the promise that is returned, but it is never executed. the application just keeps on going:

```
module.exports = async function request(requestOpts = {}) {
  console.log("5: in request... sending request")
  const response = await sendRequest({
    method: requestOpts.method,
    url: requestOpts.url,
    headers: requestOpts.headers,
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log("7: in request.. returning response")
    return response;
  })
  

};

function sendRequest(requestOpts = {}) {
  console.log("6: in sendRequest.. returning axios")
  return (
    axios({
      method: requestOpts.method,
      url: requestOpts.url,
      headers: requestOpts.headers,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log("Then ===> " + response)
      return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error ==> " + error)
      return error;
    })
    );
}
```

Step 7 never shows up.. things just move on and complete. Have I got this set up correctly? Here is the calling module:

```
module.exports = async function axiosCaller() {
    console.log('4: in axiosCaller')
    const authHeader = buildBasicAuth();
    let response = await request({
        url: 'redacted',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            authHeader
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    return handleResponse(response);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not return the async response in .then instead you need to return axios response as promise as

async sendRequest() {
return await axios(....)
}

and while calling sendRequest function you need to mention await infront of that or simply use .then to capture the response

Comment: Yessss. That was it. I spent all day on this..... Thank you!